# interpolation inequality proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations

i'm trying to solve exercise 2.15 from Gilbarg, Trudinger "elliptic partial differential equations of second order" but I'm struggling (I tried to use green's formula but I don't come much further) so I would be greatful for any kind of hint/help: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open and bounded domain Let $u \in C^2(\bar{U}), u=0$ on $\partial{U} \in C^1.$ Prove the interpolation inequality: for every $\epsilon >0 :\int_U \mid Du \mid ^2 dx \leq \epsilon \int_U(\Delta u)^2 dx +(1/4\epsilon) \int_U u^2 dx.$

Comment: Could you post your attempt with Green's formula? I'm pretty sure that's the way to go for this inequality.

Comment: @Jose27 Here is my attempt using the 1st green identity: We write $|Du|^2 = <Du,Du>$ and now we use green's identity to compute $\int_U Du \cdot Du$ dx =$ -\int_U u \Delta u dx + \int_{\partial U}  \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}u dS$  but then i don't know how to continue

Comment: The boundary term is 0 since $u$ is zero at the boundary. Can you conclude from there?

Comment: @Jose27  I think with $-xy \leq x^2/2 + y^2/2$, which follows from $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy \geq 0$ and hold for real numbers, we get $-ab \leq - (\sqrt{\epsilon}a)(b/\sqrt{\epsilon})\leq\epsilon a^2/2 + b^2/2\epsilon\leq\epsilon a^2+b^2/4\epsilon$. But I don't understand if we can treat $u$ and $\Delta u$ as real numbers. Aren't those in general vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is my proof complete now or am I doing something wrong?